# Arduino stk500_getsync(): not in sync

Tags: arduino

We have an arduino pro mini, we are trying to trying to upload sketch the controller but we are prohibited, as the arduino attempt to upload the sketch, it display an error of: not in sync.

We are pretty new in this are, so any help would be much appreciated.

Our setup is:
-Breadboard
-Connection to adapter: USB Serial.
-Arduino Pro Mini as a controller

Through the Arduino Programming Client.

The processor and the port are setup op properly.

The strange thing is, it has worked sometimes these past days..

Much Thanks.

Mieer

Comment: Try arduino.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: I didn't know there was specific arduino segment in the stack environment. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you push the "RESET" button when it starts uploading? Using the pro-mini probably you haven't connected the DTR pin, so it can't auto-reset the device (so you have to do it manually).

When Arduino starts the uploading phase just press the reset button. It should start.

Comment: Since the past time, we have upgraded our components. We work with a Bluetooth Low Energy HC-05. Yet we still have the same sync() error. What should the DTR extremity  be connected to?

Comment: the Arduino PRO mini DTR pin should be connected to the DTR serial pin. If your module doesn't have one, you'll have to do it manually (by pushing the reset button when the IDE says it's in programming mode. Someone managed to use the state pin instead, but I never tried so I don't know wheter it works properly. If you want to try simply google "hc-05 dtr" and you should find some infos

Comment: Thanks! we will try it out

Comment: Nope, no DTR on the HC-05 to be found :(